# How to design a calculator from scratch

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

A basic calculator can perform a wide variety of operations. How does the claculator 'get' the concept of adding two numbers in the same way a human does? I dont think people that make claculators store every possible result of every possible addition on the chip before shipping it. Soemhow the chip needs to 'learn' how to add.

I mean if I were to start with a blank slate(chip) and 'teach' the chip to perform calculations(additions), how do i go about it? Do i need to learn artificial nural networks first?

Comment: A pocket calculator uses logic circuits to calculate numbers. It doesn't 'get' *anything*. If you want to start with an AI and *teach* it the concept of arithmetic, that's a completely different thing from your pocket calculator.

Comment: Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29

Comment: Thanks. I can understand logical circuits for addition, but what about complex operations in a scientific calculator like the derivative of a function? or the std deviation?

Comment: How do you get the result of, say 12 + 24, yourself, using a piece of paper?  Do you have a table that has every possible result of every possible addition?  No, you use an *algorithm* ( a series of steps) to perform the calculation.  Same thing with calculators.  Algorithms to compute derivatives or std deviation work the same way; they're just a bit more complex than the addition calculation, that's all.

Comment: @Kaushik still hardware.  The VAX even had a hardware set of instructions to do polynomial evaluation. [Odd/complex vax instructions](http://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Ian/Computer_architectures#Some_interesting.2Fcomplex_VAX_instructions) - the POLYx instruction.  In hardware, designed by humans.  No machine learning or anything strange like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Work in binary: 0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101...
2. Know your math: 0+0=00, 0+1=01, 1+0=01, 1+1=10
3. Know your logic: or, and, not, xor...
4. Find that the low bit is a XOR and the high bit is a AND.
5. Expand the principle of one bit to 8, 16, 32, 64 bits
6. Build it with logic gates.

[image]

If you want to know more, see [my answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/111606/1033) to [How is fundamental mathematics efficiently evaluated by programming languages?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/110902/1033)